# WPF MVVM - Binding Command not found because of ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, datacontext, itemssource

I have a custom TabControl with an ItemsSource binded to it. Inside the ItemTemplate is a Button which Command I want to bind to a RelayCommand from my DataContext (ViewModel).

The Problem is, that the application is looking for the Command inside my ItemsSource Item.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.TabItems,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <!-- The "Header" is from the "TabItems" Model -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                <!-- I want to bind this Command outside the "TabItems" Model -->
                <Button Command="{Binding ViewModel.CounterIncrementCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox>Test</TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I get the Binding Failures:

- DataContext: TabControllitemModel
- Binding Path: ViewModel
- Target: Button.Command
- Target Type: ICommand
- Description: ViewModel property not found on object of type
  TabControlItemModel

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found it out. With this I can set the DataContext of the Button to the same one of the Window/Page:

`<Button DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" Command="{Binding ViewModel.CounterIncrementCommand}"/>`